# Blogdown site with Shiny App - Two domains needed?

Tags: r, shiny, hosting, netlify

I have created a site using RStudio/Hugo/Blogdown. Part of the site is a Shiny app, thus an iframe is used.

I believe I can host the static parts of the site with Netlify. Then configure DNS so that mydomain.com points to the site hosted by Netlify.

I also have a Digital Ocean droplet running a Shiny server. This is where the Shiny app will run.

Do I need two separate domains to make this work? mydomain.com points to Netlify. And a separate domain, myshinyapp.com, that is used by the call to the iframe.

`<iframe height="550" width="100%" frameborder="no" src="http://myshinyapp.com> </iframe>`

Is the following possible?

mydomain.com --> Netlify

mydomain.com/shinyapp --> Digital Ocean Shiny app

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I'm faced with the same issue.

Comment: Two separate domains are not required. Just use mydomain.com for Netlify and create a subdomain (ie iframe.mydomain.com/shinyapp1, iframe.mydomain.com/shinyapp2...) for as many apps as required.